# Using VBA in Excel to print pages that have values and ignore those that are blank

Tags: vba, excel, printing

I have the following code the executes when a command button is clicked on a form that has been filled out by the user.  There are five pages to the form, but 9 times out of 10 only the first and fifth pages have information on them.  Pages 2-4 are additional items, but if there is no data on them, I don't want them printed.  Currently, when I print using the code, all five pages print out.

I am looking for some help in the code to get the appropriate print area printed.  I am not sure if the final lines of the code are the issue or if it is the way the print area is computed.  Do I need to set up a range variable with the ranges in the setup or can I use the entire range in the print command to print the print area?

Thank you for any help that can be provided.  Here is the sub I am trying to run.

```
Private Sub PrintEstimate1_Click()
'   Prints the estimate upon clicking once
    Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

Dim page1 As Range
Dim page2 As Range
Dim page3 As Range
Dim page4 As Range
Dim page5 As Range

Set page1 = ws.Range("A2:I58")
Set page2 = ws.Range("A59:I116")
Set page3 = ws.Range("A117:I174")
Set page4 = ws.Range("A175:I232")
Set page5 = ws.Range("A233:I289")

Dim setup As PageSetup
Set setup = ws.PageSetup

If ws.Range("A63").Value = vbNullString Then
    setup.PrintArea = Union(page1, page5).Address
ElseIf ws.Range("A121").Value = vbNullString Then
    setup.PrintArea = Union(page1, page2, page5).Address
ElseIf ws.Range("A179").Value = vbNullString Then
    setup.PrintArea = Union(page1, page2, page3, page5).Address
Else
    setup.PrintArea = Union(page1, page2, page3, page4, page5).Address
End If

msg = "Would you like to send to default printer?"
msg = msg & vbNewLine
config = vbYesNoCancel + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton1
Title = "Printer Selection"
ans = MsgBox(msg, config, Title)

' Dialog Box to decide whether to quick print or make changes to printer setup.
If ans = vbYes Then Worksheets("PE Form").Range("A1:I288").PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
'I am not sure if it is this line above that is giving me the problem or not.
If ans = vbNo Then Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrint).Show
If ans = vbCancel Then
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you certain that A63, A121, and A179 are in fact empty? I'm assuming those tests are failing if all 5 pages print. Could those cells contain a single space? If you step through, do the `If` of `ElseIf` statements run or does it only execute the `Else`?

Comment: Yes, i have verified that the cells are empty.  When I stepped through it, it caught the first IF as A63 was blank and set the print area to Page1 and Page 5, but then when I printed, it printed all 5 pages.

Comment: `If ans = vbYes Then Worksheets("PE Form").Range("A1:I288").PrintOut` You hardcoded the range here. I think this will override your print area settings. Try `If ans = vbYes Then Worksheets("PE Form").PrintOut` (untested).

Comment: That seems to work, but now I need to figure out how to set up the actual page breaks because the pages in the code were appropriately added, but not confined to the actual pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to MoondogsMaDawg and some research on Page Breaks, I have the following revised code that seems to be functioning as intended.

```
Private Sub PrintEstimate1_Click()
'   Prints the estimate upon clicking once
    Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
ws.ResetAllPageBreaks
ws.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""

Dim setup As PageSetup
Set setup = ws.PageSetup

Dim page1 As Range
Dim page2 As Range
Dim page3 As Range
Dim page4 As Range
Dim page5 As Range

Set page1 = ws.Range("A1:I58")
Set page2 = ws.Range("A59:I116")
Set page3 = ws.Range("A117:I174")
Set page4 = ws.Range("A175:I232")
Set page5 = ws.Range("A233:I289")

ws.Rows(59).EntireRow.PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
ws.Rows(117).EntireRow.PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
ws.Rows(175).EntireRow.PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
ws.Rows(233).EntireRow.PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
ws.Columns("J").EntireColumn.PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual

If ws.Range("A63").Value = vbNullString Then
    setup.PrintArea = Union(page1, page5).Address
ElseIf ws.Range("A121").Value = vbNullString Then
    setup.PrintArea = Union(page1, page2, page5).Address
ElseIf ws.Range("A179").Value = vbNullString Then
    setup.PrintArea = Union(page1, page2, page3, page5).Address
Else
    setup.PrintArea = Union(page1, page2, page3, page4, page5).Address
End If

msg = "Would you like to send to default printer?"
msg = msg & vbNewLine
config = vbYesNoCancel + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton1
Title = "Printer Selection"
ans = MsgBox(msg, config, Title)

' Dialog Box to decide whether to quick print or make changes to printer setup.
If ans = vbYes Then Worksheets("PE Form").PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
If ans = vbNo Then Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrint).Show
If ans = vbCancel Then
End If

End Sub
```